# JVM PermGen OOM even if Max not reached yet

Tags: java, eclipse

I just got a PermGen OOM in an Eclipse 3.6 development runtime, caused by the fact that I forgot to add the required startup parameters. Before noticing that I thought something else was wrong so I fired up JVisualVM and got the following screenshot out of it:

[image: OOM Permgen]

Used is almost equals to Size, but Max is still a bit bigger. I'd expect an OOM if Used is approaching Max, not Size. The only vague explanation I have is that the JVM tries to allocate 2x the Used space which is bigger than Max. But still I'd be thankful for comments.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think Permgen is not in Xmx, they are separate. So your total of memory is at least Xms + Permgen.

Comment: Yes mate.Its related to Permgen.http://manojbardhan2009.blogspot.in/search/label/JVM%20Advance%20Setting

Answer (score 0):

Answers are right. PermGen sets independent of young and old Gen. Max is sum of all of them.
Here is an article about it
http://www.freshblurbs.com/explaining-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space

jdk has a default max value of 64 MG for PermGen. If you forgot to put the permGen it would be 64 MG max.

The picture that you copied here shows 59 MG and it is almost full. It is another indicator that shows your permGen max is 64 MG

I assume you already have changed -XX:MaxPermSize